# Is there an identity for $\hat{a}^+ \cdot \hat{a}^+$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Is there an identity for the square of the ladder operators, $\hat{a}^+$ and $\hat{a}^-$?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $\hat{a}^+$ times $\hat{a}^+$ in the title. If not please revert my edit.

Comment: What kind of identity are you looking for? Writing it in terms of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$? I mean, it's simple enough to figure out what it does to Fock states, so it's not clear what you really want here.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks, yes I did

Comment: @march I was mainly wondering if it equals a number, like 0?

Comment: Aha :-) `\dot` is the overdot operator e.g. `\dot{a}` gives $\dot{a}$. A "dot" is `\cdot`.

Comment: @Barney_Dinosaur The best way to answer this question is to act with it on the $\vert n\rangle$ states and see for yourself. Is every such vector an eigenvector of the operator with the same eigenvalue? If not, then it doesn't act as a number.

Comment: What is the dot supposed to mean? It looks like the scalar product of vectors, but ladder operators aren’t vectors.

Answer (score 2):

No!

Note that $a^{\dagger 2}$ is simply the creation operator applied twice. It does not simplify to a unique identity like the commutation relation or like writing $a a^{\dagger}$ as a function of the number operator.